# Visual basic LINQ error

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, exception, nullreferenceexception

Anyone know why I am having this error?

I am getting the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Here is the LINQ in question. Thank you for any help in advance.

```
Dim q = From line In seats
        Let data = line.Split(New [Char]() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) ' it occurs in this line '
        Let seatA = data(0)
        Let seatB = data(1)
        Let seatC = data(2)
        Let seatD = data(3)
        Let seatE = data(4)
        Let seatF = data(5)
        Where seatA Is "."
        Where seatB Is "."
        Select seatA, seatF
```

Comment: Did you try the change that I made in my answer to your last question?

Comment: This most likely means you have some `null` entries in the `seats` collection.

Comment: @MarkHall yes i tried your correction it made no difference on the LINQ. I think i might have null entries so i might try another for loop to remove them and place only valid entries into a new array. EDIT: This did not work i still get the null reference.

Comment: Ok just checking because the first answer would have given you a null entry for sure

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you change the first line to:

```
Dim windowSeatQuery = From line In seats.Where(function (s) s isnot nothing)
```

This would indicate that there a null values in the seats list, and the `Where` lambda above should remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Your Where clauses look strange to me.  Shouldn't you be using the = operator, not Is:

```
Dim q = From line In seats
    Let data = line.Split(New [Char]() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) ' it occurs in this line '
    Let seatA = data(0)
    Let seatB = data(1)
    Let seatC = data(2)
    Let seatD = data(3)
    Let seatE = data(4)
    Let seatF = data(5)
Where seatA = "." AndAlso seatB = "."   '<------   Use = on this line not Is
Select seatA, seatF
```

And are you sure that each line is delimited with spaces instead of something else?  Even having Is in there should not result in a Null Ref.

Here's my example program that seems to work (tested in LinqPad which doesn't seem to support implicit line continuation characters):

```
Sub Main
    Dim seats As New List(Of String)()
    seats.Add("1 2 3 4 5 6")
    seats.Add(". . 9 8 7 6")
    seats.Add(". . 5 5 5 5")
    seats.Add("1 2 3 4 5 6")
    seats.Add(". . 2 4 6 8")
    seats.Add("1 2 3 4 5 6")

    Dim q = From line In seats _
        Let data = line.Split(New [Char]() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) _
        Let seatA = data(0) _
        Let seatB = data(1) _
        Let seatC = data(2) _
        Let seatD = data(3) _
        Let seatE = data(4) _
        Let seatF = data(5) _
    Where seatA = "." AndAlso seatB = "." _
    Select seatA, seatF

    q.Dump()
End Sub
```